# Ball bouncing in a box, will it meet a vertex.

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I have no idea upon how to solve this:

A box 5cm by 3cm with a ball projected from a vertex at 45 degree angle, it reflexes at a 45 degree angle and keeps reflecting at a 45 degree angle. Will it meet a vertex and if so how many reflections before contact with vertex?

I have mental image the problem, but how to make that math?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can unfold the trajectory of the ball and reflect the box instead. This gives us a $5\times 3$ grid in the plane and the question is whether the diagonal line through the origin will ever meet a lattice point again, and  if so after crossing how many vertical or horizontal grid lines?
Cast into a formula: Do there exist natural numbers $n,m$ with $(5n,3m)$ on the diagonal, i.e. with $5n=3m$? And what is the smallest such pair?
An obvious candidate is $n=3$, $m=5$ because $5\cdot 3=3\cdot 5$, and in this case it is also the minimal solution because $\gcd(3,5)=1$. So the point itself is $(15,15)$ and the trajectory crosses $n-1$ vertical and $m-1$ horizontal lines until there (namely $x=5$, $x=10$, $y=3$, $y=6$, $y=9$, $y=12$). So the answer is: Yes, after six reflections.

Comment: I understand the mathematical equations, but the part about unfold the trajectory and lattice points,diagonal line (I know it is a line from one vertex to another vertex and there are two of them)...do not understand. Could you please explain at a more simple level, or explain what those parts mean. Very thank you.

Comment: See my picture below for one way to think about the "unfolding". A lattice point is just an intersection of two (or more) grid lines. By "diagonal line" he means the 45 degree trajectory of the ball. So you set up the grid, launch the ball, and see where it hits a lattice point.

Answer (score 4):

To accompany Hagen's great response, here is a pictorial solution. 
[image]

Comment: WOW, that really helped explain my questions about Hagen von Eitzen answer. Great job.